# Safety and translation of query params in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, rails-i18n

I have a two part question. I'm passing params to links in order to sort and filter in my Ruby on Rails app. Is this type of resulting url safe?

```
/realestates?column=salesprice&direction=desc
```

If not, what would be the best way to hide the column name?

The second part of my question is what's the best way to translate these params to different languages. I have i18n set up. This is an example of a link with parameters:

```
<%= link_to realestates_path(column: :salesprice, direction: 'desc') do %>
 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>Order by price
<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "safe"? From what?

Comment: Normally localization doesn't go as deep as the parameters level. If you're going to be sharing these URLs and don't want non-localized text in them, consider using shorthand, like `d` instead of `direction`.

Comment: [Ask only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735). Read the [Help Center on Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @tadman thank you for your answer. I meant if it's safe from sql injection.. thank you for your second comment, it's a very good option, I'll do that! I don't know how to accept your answer, since it's a comment. Have a nice night!

Comment: URLs do not cause SQL injection. That's caused by, not surprisingly, injecting into your SQL. If you use ActiveRecord properly this is not a risk. If you're composing your own queries be sure to use placeholder values, as in `User.where(id: n)` is fine, but `User.where("id={params[:id}")` is absolutely not. In Rails you generally have to go out of your way to mess things up.

Comment: Regarding your second question, is there a requirement to localize the params in the URL? That is quite strange. There may not be a good way of doing that as the URL is not intended for human consumption.

Comment: Hi @BSeven no there is no requirement, it's my own project, I've since checked some big websites and seen that params are not translated. Thank you!